# how to generate random numbers from a shifted to the left chi square distribution in R?

Tags: r, random

I want to generate random numbers from chi-square distribution with 3 degrees of freedom but shifted to the left . I mean the shifted distribution function f(x-a) a is the amount of shifting.

in r it is said the non centrality parameter must be non negative.

Comment: So if you want `n` random numbers, what's wrong with `rchisq(n, 3) - a`?

Comment: @Peter O i thought it is like rnorm .when i wanted to generate from shifted to theleft normal distribution i used write the following: rnorm(10,-2,1) so replacing the mean 0 by 0-2= -2 give shifeted random varivables .i was wondering if it is the same with non centrality parametr and then i was blocked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the Chi-square distribution with 3 degrees of freedom:

```r
x_vals <- seq(0, 10, 0.1)

plot(x_vals, dchisq(x_vals, 3), type = "l", 
     main = "Chi Squared distribution of x with 3 DOF")
```

[image]

Now let's shift it to the left by a constant `a`. We'll plot a vertical line at x = 0 to emphasize the shift:

```r
a <- 2
plot(x_vals - a, dchisq(x_vals, 3), type = "l",
     main = "Chi Squared distribution of x - 2 with 3 DOF")
abline(v = 0, lty = 2)
```

[image]

This is the distribution from which you wish to sample. That being the case, we need only sample from the Chi-square distribution and subtract `a` from each element drawn. In R this is as easy as doing `rchisq(n, 3) - a` where `n` is the desired sample size.

To demonstrate, here is a histogram of 10,000 samples drawn from this distribution:

```r
hist(rchisq(10000, 3) - a, breaks = 100, xlim = c(-2, 8), 
     main = "10,000 samples from Chi Square distribution of (x - 2) with 3 DOF")
```

[image]